# Positioning two blocks on the same line

Tags: css

I have this HTML code:

```
<span class="left">
        <img class="avatar" src="image.jpg" />
</span>
<span class="right">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nunc euismod nisl nam euismod, quis maecenas blandit ac, neque sed ut pulvinar, lectus sagittis sapien mauris per risus vel. Ligula sapien sed morbi cras tellus commodo. Rutrum mattis accumsan, hac sed praesent, neque tortor neque, commodo mauris sagittis turpis, faucibus sed ultrices tempor interdum. Lobortis assumenda nisl, posuere cras sit risus egestas bibendum nec, magna in, sed mattis pharetra felis nulla vitae aptent, in semper et...
</span>
```

I would that the two blocks are positioned on the same line. I use this CSS:

```
.right {
width: 250px;
background-color: orange;
float: left;
} 

.left {
width: 100px;
background-color: orange;
float: left;
}
```

It's good, but I want that the right side (the text) is not large 250px, but 100%. If I put width:100%, the block is not on the same line.

How can I do this?

Comment: 100% of what? what is the size for their parent's?

Comment: 100% of the page, I want to use all the width that is on the right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution to your problem - you set the width on the left item, and the margin on the right item. The left item is floated, the right item isn't. I have also made the display of the right item "block".

```
.right {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 100px;
    width: auto;
    background-color: orange;
} 

.left {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: orange;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For floated elements, if you want to use percentage widths, you should calculate the width of each:

```
.right {
width: 50%; /*or 45%*/
background-color: orange;
float: left;
} 

.left {
width: 50%; /*or 55%*/
background-color: orange;
float: left;
}
```

Then they will display on the same line.

Also, if there are margins or paddings, you should take this into consideration when calculating the widths as if you set both to 50% but there is a margin of 10px, it will still force the next element onto a new line.

To make the `.right` element calculate the width, you need to set its width to `width: auto;` and counter-margin the `.left` element: `margin-left; 100px;` (where 100px is equal to the `.left` elemtents width).

[Example for you here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/QydGs/).

Answer (score 0):

delete the width for the right class and the float. This will make the right class to get the remaining width of the parent element.

```
.right {
    background-color: orange;
}
.left {
    width:250px;
    background-color: orange;
    float:left;
}
```

example http://jsbin.com/ayaha3